# Prompting for User Name with Omniauth-Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I'm using Devise with my Rails app and I'm looking at using the [Omniauth-Facbook gem](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook).  My app has views that show the users's by user name.  What I haven't been able to figure out is how I can prompt a user for a user name when doing this.

I know that I can request this from Facebook, if the user has created a FB user name.  Many people have not specified a user name for their FB account, so this does not seem like the best approach.  I've read other answers which indicate that perhaps the email should be used instead, which works if the user name is solely for logging on, but this is obviously not a good idea if the user name is going to be shown on user views.

If anyone could provide guidance on how to best prompt or get a user name while registering someone through Omniauth-Facebook, that would be very appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

when you sign up for facebook, then check whether they have username in the facebook, if no,then just redirect to your path to update the username?